# db query: one field ok to be null, another not "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'"

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two columns in a DB table, the schema is this:

`columnA` text DEFAULT NULL,

`columnB`  varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,

In the DbContext they are declared like this:

```
public byte[] columnA { get; set; }
public string columnB { get; set; }
```

If I set in my table `columnA = null` for some record, everything is fine, no problems.
If I set in my table `columnB = null` for some record (no other differences), the EntityFrameworkCore layer throws an exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type whatever.
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
> at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Row.cs:line 377

Everything works fine when `columnB` is not null for that record; keeping everything the same, and only changing `columnB` for one record to be `null`, causes the exception.
The code that crashes is simply a query to the DB that would return (among others) the item with a null field.

```
var itemQuery = _myDbContext.Item.Where(a => a.id == id);
if (!await itemQuery.AnyAsync()) {...}
var listOfItems = itemQuery.ToList(); // this is where it crashes.
```

Here is what I tried:

- Declare columnB as `public string? columnB {get;set;}`. Made no difference.
- I re-defined columnB in the schema to be also `text`, instead of `varchar(250)`. I updated the DB, confirmed that everything works fine if columnB is not null. Then I made it null again (manually) for one record, and it still crashed.
- I found a workaround where I just catch the exception, and just carry on, but that’s not really a solution.

I'd like to understand *why* this is happening, and why is it a problem for `columnB` but it is not a problem for `columnA`, and how/if I can fix it so that `columnB` can also be `null`?

Thank you very much for reading and for any suggestions or ideas.
Edit: as requested, the stack trace:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'MyApp.Database.MyAppDbContext'.
      System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
         at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Row.cs:line 377
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 272
         at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Row.cs:line 377
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 272
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Please paste the full exception call stack as text: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered a similar error the solution that worked was to explicitly check the data coming from the database for System.DBNull values. It's not clear from your question how you're getting the data from the database but in my case I filled up DataTable objects and then checked the incoming values like so:

```
using System.Data;
(...)
DataTable dt;
(...)
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) //iterate through all rows of the datatable
{
    if (dr["columnB"] != System.DBNull.Value)
    {
        //cast value of dr["columnB"] appropriately and store it in a local variable
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this style before, but I was a bit reluctant to adopt it, as it is different from what is used everywhere else in the codebase. Right now, I'm pulling the data from the database with the LINQ query I mentioned, using the DbContext: `var itemQuery = _myDbContext.Item.Where(a => a.id == id);` I'm new at this - doing the way you suggested, how is that scalable? I would have to manually save each column in a variable...for dozens of columns. Is that the generally-accepted practice? Thank you again for your response!

Comment: What type of database is your source?

Comment: t4r4z0k: mysql. Thank you again for helping out! Is there any other info I could provide?